# Why solr error in logs when adding documents

Tags: spring-boot, solr, solr9

I am getting Error when am adding document. My process will be deleting document with id and adding whole document again.
I am using spring boot solr to do this operations.
Most of the time document is added but some time I see it is missing
in solr 9 logs I see this error

I don't have groups value in my document at all

**Unknown operation for the an atomic update: GROUPS**

schema.xml

```
<field name="groups" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```